# Can the four Seasons of planet Earth be defined in terms of Energy?

Tags: thermodynamics, energy, astronomy, earth, sun

Can the four Seasons of planet Earth be defined in terms of Energy?

The definition of Energy gotten from Google is:

> ability to do work, which is the ability to exert a force causing displacement of an object.”

To make things a little bit more simple, count only non artificial "events".
 Can there be such a definition? 
Image below might be of help.

[image]

Comment: What is that image supposed to be showing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure. The seasons are defined by the total energy flux imparted by the sun onto a given hemisphere of the planet.

During summer, a given hemisphere is tilted towards the sun, so there is more incident light upon it. That means a greater energy flux for that hemisphere.

During winter, a given hemisphere is tilted away from the sun, so there is less incident light upon it. That means a lesser energy flux for that hemisphere.

Comment: Thank you Logan. This a very simple answer. Dive deeper.